# Ubuntu 20.04 multi screen error when not mirroring

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have following issue with dual screen on xubuntu 20.04.
I have two monitors:

```
VGA-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 480mm x 270mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
DVI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 510mm x 287mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
S-video disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And graphic card:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV370 [Radeon X300]
```

when I have option "mirror image" checked, everything work just fine. But when I uncheck it, everything start to shimmer and random color strips appear across both screens.

Can you help me with this one?